# A better way to avoid public member invisibility and source code bloat/repetition with inherited class templates?

Tags: c++, templates

**Context**:
Inheritance of protected and public class members is a fundamental concept of Object Oriented Programming.  The trivial example below illustrates an often encountered situation in which the class `CDerived` inherits all public members of the class `CBase` and adds 1 additional function of its own **without** changing nor explicitly redeclaring nor redefining any of the public members of the `CBase` class.

```
#include <stdio.h>

class CBase
{
public:
    char Arr[32];

    int Fn1(void) {
        return Arr[1] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr)-1];
    }

    int Fn2(void) {
        return Arr[2] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr)-2];
    }
};


class CDerived : public CBase
{
public:  
    int FnSum(void) {
        return Fn1() + Fn2();
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    CDerived ddd;

    printf("%d\n", ddd.Fn1());
    printf("%d\n", ddd.Fn2());
    printf("%d\n", ddd.FnSum());

    return (int)ddd.Arr[0];
};
```

The code above compiles without problems on all major compilers.

However, if one wishes to "*templatize*" this code, e.g.: by parametrizing the size of the `Arr` array, then all **public members** of `CBase` class template **become invisible** to the `CDerived` class template on compilers that conform to the latest C++ standard.
Below is the problem code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

template <unsigned int BYTES>
class CBase
{
public:
    char Arr[BYTES];

    int Fn1(void) {
        return Arr[1] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr)-1];
    }

    int Fn2(void) {
        return Arr[2] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr)-2];
    }
};

template <unsigned int BYTES>
class CDerived : public CBase<BYTES>
{
public:

    int FnSum(void) {
        return Fn1() + Fn2() + Arr[0];  // ERRORs: identifiers "Fn1" and "Fn2" and "Arr" are NOT found !
    }
};    

int main(void)
{
    CDerived<32> ddd;

    printf("%d\n", ddd.Fn1());  //No error here
    printf("%d\n", ddd.Fn2());  //No error here
    printf("%d\n", ddd.FnSum());

    return (int)ddd.Arr[0];   //No error here
}
```

See:
MSVC v19.10: https://godbolt.org/g/eQKDhb
ICC v18.0.0: https://godbolt.org/g/vBBEQC
GCC v8.1:    https://godbolt.org/g/GVkeDh

There are 4 solutions to this problem:

**Solution #1**: Prefix all of the references to members of the `CBase` class template (even the public ones), with `CBase<BYTES>::` like this:

```
 int FnSum(void) {
        return CBase<BYTES>::Fn1() + CBase<BYTES>::Fn2() + CBase<BYTES>::Arr[0];  
 }
```

See:
MSVC v19.10: https://godbolt.org/g/48ZJrj
ICC v18.0.0: https://godbolt.org/g/BSPcSQ
GCC v8.1:    https://godbolt.org/g/Vg4SZM

**Solution #2**: Prefix all of the references to members of the `CBase` class template (even the public ones), with `this->` like this:

```
 int FnSum(void) {
        return this->Fn1() + this->Fn2() + this->Arr[0];  
 }
```

See:
MSVC v19.10: https://godbolt.org/g/oBs6ud
ICC v18.0.0: https://godbolt.org/g/CWgJWu
GCC v8.1:    https://godbolt.org/g/Gwn2ch

**Solution #3**: Add one `using` statement inside the `CDerived` class template, for each member of the `CBase` (even a public one) that is referenced by the `CDerived`, like this:

```
using CBase<BYTES>::Arr;
using CBase<BYTES>::Fn1;
using CBase<BYTES>::Fn2;
```

See:
MSVC v19.10: https://godbolt.org/g/gJT8cX
ICC v18.0.0: https://godbolt.org/g/1RK84A
GCC v8.1:    https://godbolt.org/g/d8kjFh

**Solution #4**: Disable the strict conformance to the C++ standard by enabling the "permissive" mode in the compiler settings, like this:

For MSVC v19.10 remove the switch `/permissive-`, see: https://godbolt.org/g/Yxw89Y
For ICC v18.0.0 add the switch `-fpermissive`, see: https://godbolt.org/g/DwuTb4
For GCC v8.1 add the switch `-fpermissive`, see: https://godbolt.org/g/DHGBpW

*MSVC NOTE:  According to **[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance)**, by default the `/permissive-` option is set in new projects created by Visual Studio 2017 v15.5 (MSVC compiler v19.11) and later versions. It is not set by default in earlier versions, ...including the latest Godbolt.org's Compiler Explorer MSVC version v19.10.*

*GCC NOTE:  Even with the `-fpermissive` compiler switch, the GCC v8.1 compiler still needs the `using CBase<BYTES>::Arr;` statement inside the `CDerived` class (...or one of the other solutions) in order to make the public `Arr` array visible inside the `CDerived` class template ...but it does not need anything extra to make the `Fn1()` and `Fn2()` functions visible.*

**MSVC Non-Solution**:
According to **[this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase)** and **[this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/09/11/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/)**, the compilation error in MSVC comes from the Two-Phase Name Lookup being enabled by the conformance to the C++ standard mode ( the `/permissive-` option).
Also, according to the [former article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-twophase): "*The `/permissive-` option implicitly sets the conforming two-phase lookup compiler behavior, but it can be overridden by using `/Zc:twoPhase-` switch*".
However adding the two compiler switches `/permissive- /Zc:twoPhase-` does not cause the "templated" problem code to compile in MSVC v19.14, without the additions described in Solution #1 or #2 or #3.
MSVC v19.14: https://godbolt.org/z/BJlyA8

See **[this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50333246/why-does-the-zctwophase-compiler-switch-has-no-effect-in-msvc)** for more details.

**Problems with above Solutions**:
Solution #4 is not portable and breaks away from the C++ standard. It is also a GLOBAL solution (global switch) to a local problem - usually a bad idea. A compiler switch that affects only a portion of the code (e.g. `#pragma NOtwoPhase`) does not exist.
Solution #1 has an unintended side-effect of suppressing virtual calls, thus it is not applicable in general case.
Both solutions #1 and #2 require many verbose additions to the code.  This leads to a **source code bloat that does not add any new functionality**.  For example if the `CDerived` class template adds only 2 functions to a `CBase` class that contains 5 public functions and 1 member variable, which are referenced multiple times in `CDerived`, the Solution #1 requires **14 verbose code alterations/additions** in the derived class, which look like this:

```
    #include <stdio.h> 

    template <unsigned int BYTES>
    class CBase
    {
    public:
        char Arr[BYTES];

        CBase() {
            for (size_t i=1; i<sizeof(Arr); i++)
            Arr[i] = Arr[i-1]+(char)i;
        }   

        int Fn1(void) {
            return Arr[1] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr)-1];
        }

        int Fn2(void) {
            return Arr[2] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr) - 2];
        }

        int Fn3(void) {
            return Arr[3] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr) - 3];
        }

        int Fn4(void) {
            return Arr[4] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr) - 4];
        }

        int Fn5(void) {
            return Arr[5] ^ Arr[sizeof(Arr) - 5];
        }
    };


    template <unsigned int BYTES>
    class CDerived : public CBase<BYTES>
    {
    public:

        int FnSum(void) {
            return CBase<BYTES>::Fn1() +
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn2() + 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn3() + 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn4() + 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn5() + 
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[0] +
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[1] +
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[2];
        }

        int FnProduct(void) {
            return CBase<BYTES>::Fn1() * 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn2() * 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn3() * 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn4() * 
            CBase<BYTES>::Fn5() * 
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[0] *
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[1] *
            CBase<BYTES>::Arr[2];
        }  
    };

    int main(void)
    {
        CDerived<32> ddd;

        printf("%d\n", ddd.FnSum());
        printf("%d\n", ddd.FnProduct());

        return (int)ddd.Arr[0];
    }
```

In real life the Base class template might contain ~50 functions and many variables which are referenced multiple times in the Derived class template, which necessitate 100s of such repetitive edits ! 
There must be a better way...

Solution #3 requires less work because it does not require finding and prefixing EVERY REFERENCE to the `CBase` member in the `CDerived`'s code.  The `CBase` members, that are used by `CDerived`, need to be "re-declared" with a `using` statement **only once**, regardless how many times these members are used/referenced in the `CDerived`'s code.  This saves a lot of mindless searching and typing.

Unfortunately a blanket statement like `using CBase<BYTES>::*` which makes all of the protected and public members visible in the derived class template, does not exist.

**QUESTION**:
Is there a less verbose portable solution to this problem ?  e.g. Solution #5...

Comment: compile with -Os?

Comment: "Solution #1" has an unintended side-effect of suppressing virtual calls. It is not applicable in general case.

Comment: Snark aside, you should provide us with a reason why you worry about code bloat in unoptimized code, since the As-if rule of the standard brushes all these concerns away.

Comment: @Frank, I am not worrying about the compiled machine code bloat.  I am worrying about the C++ source code bloat.

Comment: @KarolaN -- With your scenario, you may want to consider writing a template meta-function that recursively adds, multiplies, etc. at compile time.

Comment: @KarolaN Fair enough. The godbolt links led me to make a bad assumption.

Comment: Whenever a hard problem appears in C++, your first thought should probably be "oh god, not macros!" ... because they're still so very useful.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, That code is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE) as suggested by StackOveflow guidelines.  It is about the visibility of inherited class template members, not about that specific addition and multiplication example.

Comment: Code bloat is the inevitable result of each template instance being a discrete class. Using virtual function-based type erasure, where the template inherits from its base classes will collapse the base classes and eliminate the code bloat, at expense of fewer possible compile-time optimizations, and the fact that all template instances have the same base classes, which may or may not be desirable, as it, somewhat, reduces type safety.

Comment: There's a zero-sum solution:  Add the `this->` where necessary, but subtract the `int` when preceded by `unsigned`, and subtract the `void` as a parameter.  This works and keeps source code bloat to existing levels and perhaps even decreases them. :-)

Comment: If using heap memory instead of stack memory is possible, you could use a pointer instead of an array. 

Then instead of having a templated class, use a templated member function `template<unsigned int BYTES> CBase::initialize() {Arr= new char[BYTES]}` (and add a `delete [] Arr` in CBase destructor).

In the constructor of CDerived call `CBase::initialize<BYTES()` function with your template argument.

Comment: As far as I understand solution #1 and #2 can hardly work, because the offending templated class may appear in further templated classes. There the offending method may be invisible again in the first of the two pass compilation phases. I would go with solution #3 and not simplify that with macros.

Comment: The “new functionality” is that members added in revisions or specializations of the base class template do not hijack uses of namespace members (as well as a uniform syntax for references to dependent class members).  (Did you suppose that the language designers added the requirement for the **purpose** of syntactic overhead?)  Incidentally, you can just write the **current** class’s name (`CDerived::Arr`), which is helpful if there are many template arguments.  Finally, either you have enough references that `using` is relatively cheap, or few enough that `this->` is cheap, so why worry?

Answer (score 7):

Use macros to simplify Solution #3 somewhat. Boost is not strictly necessary, but makes life easier.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>

#define USING_ONE(r, base, member)              \
    using base::member;

#define USING_ALL(base, ...)                    \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH(                      \
        USING_ONE, base,                        \
        BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)   \
    )

// Near CBase<BYTES>
#define USING_CBASE(param) USING_ALL(CBase<param>, Arr, Fn1, Fn2, Fn3, Fn4, Fn5)

// In CDerived<BYTES>, in a `public:` section
USING_CBASE(BYTES);
```

Comment: Moar parentheses in case `base` contains commas, please.

Answer (score 2):

I was suffering from the same issue.
I went through All Solutions posted by George Robinson.
While I found **Solution #2** and **Solution #3** the most helpful and concise with the least CodeSmell. I try to avoid using any naked pointers and I rarely use the `this` Keyword and hence didn't want to use **Solution #2**.

However while I was writing the code for Template Inheritance involving some fairly complex templates.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Runnable{
  // Class Code
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
class Task: Runnable<vector<pair<T1,T2>>,vector<pair<T3,T4>>> {
  // Derived Class Code
};
```

clearly applying Solution#3 was not favorable to me and hence. I found a work around that to me was cleared and made the code a bit nicer as well.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4>
class Outer{
  public: 
    using Runnable_ = Runnable<vector<pair<T1,T2>>,vector<pair<T3,T4>>>;

    class Task: Runnable_{
      // Inner Class Code
      // Need to use only Runnable_ instead of Runnable<vector<pair<T1,T2>>,vector<pair<T3,T4>>>
      using Runnable_ run;
      // Remaining Class Code

    };

};

Outer<int, int, int, int>::Task task;
```

While this isn't as efficient as the Boost Solution. It helps a lot while writing complicated template classes without using `this->`.

When writing nested template classes the `Outer` class is usually necessary and thus the overhead in terms of code is much lower.